# nginx - get parsed server_name

Tags: nginx, redirection

I have created virtual hosts for my websites and then i have created an other virtual host with `server_name -> default_server` in order to catch everything else and show a specific page in that case (ex. if someone tries to access my ip).

Also i use phpmyadmin, roundcube and squirrelmail and i wanted to redirect any connection to them from http to https. And here is the problem:

Lets say i type: `http://44.44.44.44/phpmyadmin`  (assume `44.44.44.44` is my ip)

Because i have set `server_name -> default_server`

```
server {

    listen 80;

    server_name default_server;

    root /usr/share/nginx/www;
    index index.html index.htm;


    location /phpmyadmin {
            rewrite     ^   https://$server_name$request_uri? permanent;
    }

    [...]
}
```

The url to which i am redirected is  not `https://44.44.44.44/phpmyadmin` but `https://default_server/phpmyadmin` which of course doesn't exist.

So i ended up pointing explicitly to my ip:

```
location /phpmyadmin {
        rewrite     ^   https://44.44.44.44$request_uri? permanent;
}
```

It works like this, but i was wondering if there is a way to do the same thing using a variable that returns the parsed server_name or any other / smarter way.

Comment: You can see a list of all available variables at http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#variables . You may also use $host, aside from what's already mentioned in the answer below

Comment: default_server doesn't mean anything special to server_name.  It's a listen parameter: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#listen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `$http_host` instead of `$server_name`.

```
            rewrite     ^   https://$http_host$request_uri? permanent;
```